# How to make selection color be "on top" when background color for any text element is set in Visual Studio 2010 editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, colors, background-color

Faced problem while setting background color for any element in Visual Studio 2010 editor. Selection color doesn't override this background color. So then it's very inconvenient to work with selections in editor.

Case when only string literal is selected it's almost impossible to distinguish colors and see what part of string is selected.

Is there any possibility to fix the problem by changing some options? Or it's a Visual Studio bug?

Comment: Are you talking about the fact that the selection is partially transparent, and thus blends with the other background colors?  If so, someone else wrote an extension to disable that.  If you let me know, I can get him to send you a copy.

Answer (score 0):

This is new VS2010 behavior which unfortunately is deliberate.  However, Noah Richards (from the editor team) has written a couple of extensions that help mitigate the new behavior:

The first is an [extension that draws a border around the selection](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7687f71d-49aa-4cbd-b0ad-6f90c9a64572) (the main feature of the extension is a gradient background, but the border is what makes it really useful for me).

Second is an extension to change [Selection Foreground](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7ed8bf5b-f62b-477b-b221-ab8f7216ee36) color.